# How to get metadata of RTSP in Python?

Tags: python, metadata, rtsp

I have such URL:`rtsp://admin:campas123@172.27.202.226:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0`
and I want to know exact timestamp of each frame.

Actually I'm developing optical speed estimation system and usually, cameras don't have stable FPS. So I need to know the exact time between frames.

Comment: Uhhh...If the camera doesn't have a stable FPS, it probably means that it doesn't have a stable clock. Even if the frames are timestamped beyond the frame number, you can't very well  trust the camera's clock.